# How to store user sensitive information locally?

Tags: java, encryption, passwords, user-data, sensitive-data

I am developing an application that is asking the user to enter his account name and password in order to log in to an online forum, among other things.

Please note that **I am not** actually transmitting any data over the Internet through my application and I am only connecting to a particular server. I am using [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to grab a link to the forum, get the correct login form, fill in the data and submit it. The actual data relay over the net is managed by a 3rd party company.

Now to the actual problem:

Some users would like to be able to save their credentials so they won't have to retype them anytime they start the app.

I am saving their credentials to a `.txt` file whose contents I am encrypting using a `Password Based Encryption with MD5 and DES algorithm` with a `static password` and a `static salt`. I am mainly encrypting those files so if they accidentally send this file over to someone they won't be able to get that information out so easily and hopefully avoid the hassle.

To my understanding, since I am a total noob to cryptography, using a hardcoded salt along with a hardcoded password is not a very secure technique, however it is probably sufficient when I am saving data locally. *Am I right here?*

Also is `.txt` files a secure way of storing such data? If no what would you suggest?

Comment: I think its probably fine as long as the data itself is encrypted and hashed. Now reversing hashing you can't really do (or supposed to be able to do). So use some encryption algorithm with salt only you know or your program can calculate.

Comment: It might be better to ask on [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you want to roll your own for fun or education, cool. If not, there are libraries to do this stuff for you. Jasypt is one such lib.

Comment: Anyone who has access to your app can extract the password, get the encrypted files, and decrypt them, reading the user's plaintext credentials, right?

Comment: @DavidConrad Supposing that they have access to the files of the other users then yes but that would mean their system is already compromised. I am storing each file locally, on the machines of the users. This file is **never** relayed through the internet and is only accessed when encrypting/decrypting.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, your solution is good enough. Strongly encrypted or not this information lays in the user computer, and can only be stolen if his system is compromised, in which case there are dozens of other ways of obtaining this password doesn't matter how safely you store it or even if you don't store it at all.

The only security layer I'd add is to make sure this credentials file cannot be simply copied to another computer with your software and used from there. To prevent that you can include system specs in your salt, such as partition serial number etc.

Comment: As far as I understand hard disk serial numbers are not completely unique but finding 2 disks with identical serial numbers is rather rare. This was an excellent idea, thank you.

Comment: Scrap that last comment, I just realised you were talking about the serial number that is assigned to a disk by the OS and not the serial number encoded in the firmware of the disk. Thank you again.

Comment: Better yet, use the primary Ethernet adapter's MAC address. It seems to be a popular hardware reference lately. Not sure how you get it though.

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is that the user may accidentally send the file to someone else, it may be better encryption to use a stronger algorithm like AES 256.

Comment: I am sorry again, I am a total sucker when it comes to cryptography, doesn't AES still use a key to encrypt/decrypt data which I would have to hardcode in my application? The assaulter will still have access to an easy decrypt tool if he gets his hands on the file. I dont see where would your suggestion be useful. Please enlighten me.

Comment: I am not sure I understand app's operation:if the .txt file is accessed,used to populate the user credentials each time, encrypted contents could still populate the fields (decrypt via ASP on server).If the .txt file is for user's convenience, not directly accessed by the app,they can store their password elsewhere (secure vault, on another device, etc.). MD5 wiki mentions breaking its encryption (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), as does DES (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFF_DES_cracker). I believe AES 256 is stronger (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).